# MYSQL SELECT INTO OUTPUT FILE permission other than 640

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ftp

I'm using Mysql 8.0.29 on Ubuntu 21.10.
That query works fine :

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1,field2
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM mtable WHERE id < 20;
```

But the file created at permission 640 and I can't get it by ftp download.

I edit the /etc/init.d/mysql file and restarted the server :

```
UMASK=0640
export UMASK
UMASK_DIR=0750
export UMASK_DIR
```

But still permission 640 on the file.

Comment: I don't know how to persuade mysql to save files with different permissions, but you could try altering the file permissions using chmod 644 output.csv and it might keep those rather than replacing the file with a 640 one. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but it won't be possible to execute chmod in the front end of my application.

Comment: I thought you might only have to do it once and mysql continue to use the new file permissions.

Comment: Only for that same file or even for the new ones?

Comment: Only for that filename.

Comment: Okay, but it can't help me much since my application should create file names on the fly.

Comment: Have you considered the security implications of what you're doing? You want to be able to download by ftp any mysql outfile? To do that, you could just add whatever user your ftp app uses to the mysql group, but this is a security risk.

Comment: Yes, only for those that I put in that /tmp folder. Security isn't that big of a deal for what I'm building.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the MySQL group angle. I'll try that.

Comment: You'll need to limit what directories your ftp app can access I think. I don't know how you can do this in a safer way.

Comment: My FTP can see the files but can't download them, because my FTP uses ubuntu's credentials to access the folder. How can I  add that ubuntu user to the MySql group? I'm still searching for how to do that.

Comment: @SimonGoater MySQL'S SELECT INTO OUTFILE won't use the same file for subsequent exports. It only writes to a new file each time.